Use SavedStateHandle to pass data between fragments with Navigation Component
recently I have been learning about SavedStateHandle. I know it can handle configuration changes, but when I tried to use it to receive data from another Fragment, I was still able to receive the data as usual.
I am not exactly sure how SavedStateHandle works and if using it to transfer data between Fragments would cause any issues.
Could someone please explain it to me?
The code snippet below is an example of how I pass and receive data using SavedStateHandle:
In first Fragment:
 findNavController().navigate( R.id.ringtonesDetailFragment, bundleOf(SOUND_KEY to "KeyDATA"))


In second Fragment's viewModel:
   var soundModel = savedStateHandle.get<SoundModel>(RingtonesDetailFragment.SOUND_KEY)

